# Rails - When to escape ampersands in query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, web, query-string

In the following situations which is correct?

```
class SomeController
  def action
    yada yada
    value = CGI.escape(value)
    value2 = CGI.escape(value2)
    redirect_to "http://boogeywoogey.com?key=#{value}&key2=#{value2}"
    redirect_to "http://boogeywoogey.com?key=#{value}&amp;key2=#{value2}"
  end
end
```

Or in the view,

```
link_to "http://urlwithnohelper.com?key=value&key2=value2"
link_to "http://urlwithnohelper.com?key=value&amp;key2=value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is placing a link to a different site, why create a controller action and have to serve a request that isn't necessary?

Comment: You're only redirected to the 3rd party under certain conditions that are determined within the controller action. Regardless, I'm refactoring existing controllers trying to eliminate issues with double encoded columns ending up in our analytics data.  "&amp;amp;amp;"